# Renumbering Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a question about XSLT 1.0.I have the following XML:

```
<A Start="1000">
 <B>
  <C Number="14">
  <C Number="22">
  <C Number="56">
 </B>
 <B>
  <C Number="19">
  <C Number="25">
  <C Number="112">
 </B>
</A>
```

and would like to get this result XML with an XSLT.

```
<A Start="1000">
 <B>
  <C Number="14" New="1001">
  <C Number="22" New="1002">
  <C Number="56" New="1003">
 </B>
 <B>
  <C Number="19" New="1004">
  <C Number="25" New="1005">
  <C Number="112" New="1006">
 </B>
</A>
```

I would like to use the "Start" attribute of **A** for renumbering.
The **C** should be incremented starting from the attribute "Start". But this should be done comprehensively.

Is this possible somehow?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="C">
    <xsl:variable name="num" >
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <C Number="{@Number}" New="{ancestor::A/@Start + $num}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```